# Are distributions close in total variation also close in mean?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider two probability distributions $P$ and $Q$ over (subset of) $\mathbb{R}$ such that variance of both $P$ and $Q$ is at most $\sigma^2$ and total variation distance between $P$ and $Q$ is at most $\alpha$. My question is, can I then conclude that the difference in means of $P$ and $Q$ is at most $f(\alpha, \sigma^2)$? If yes, then what is $f$?

I know that $f(\alpha, \sigma^2)\geq C \sigma \alpha$ where $C$ is an absolute constant just by considering the case when $P$ and $Q$ are univariate Gaussians, and using the fact that total variance between gaussians with the same variance is about difference in means divided by standard deviation. I am wondering if it is possible to obtain a general formula for $f$.

Comment: Is $\alpha+2\sigma$ a reasonable bound for you?

Comment: Sure. Although I think that there should be multiplicative factor of $\sigma$, since I can scale the random variables distributed as $P$ and $Q$ and the total variation distance doesn't change. However, the difference in mean and standard deviation gets scaled by the same factor.